# List(Of List(Of String)) to List(Of String)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My question is pretty straight forward

How can I convert `List(Of List(Of String))` to `List(Of String)`?

any hints would be really appreciated!

Comment: What is the way you want to convert, do you want to concatenate them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var listOfListOfStrings = 
    new List<List<string>> {new List<string> {"one"}, new List<string> {"two"}};

var listOfStrings = new List<string>();

listOfStrings.AddRange(listOfListOfStrings.SelectMany(l => l));
```

or just:

```
var listOfStrings = listOfListOfStrings.SelectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to concatenate all of the lists, you can do this with Linq using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Dim result As List(Of String) = source.SelectMany(Function(innerList) innerList).ToList()
```

Comment: Would this not return IEnumerable(Of String) as opposed to List(Of String())?

Comment: @Ric is right, and adding `.ToList` will make it a `List(Of String)`. Note that `List(Of String)` is what the question asks for, not `List(Of String())`.

Comment: Yep, I missed the .ToList. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following method tested and it is working fine:

```
Dim newList As New List(Of String)
For Each L In MyListOfList
    newList.AddRange(L)
Next
```